# Creating a couchdb view to index if item in an array exists

Tags: indexing, couchdb

I have the following sample documents in my couchdb. The original table in production has about 2M records.

```
{ 
  {
      "_id": "someid|goes|here",
      "collected": {
          "tags": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "someid1|goes|here",
      "collected": {
           "tags": ["abc", "klm","pqr"]
      },
  },
  {
      "_id": "someid2|goes|here",
      "collected": {
           "tags": ["efg", "hij","klm"]
      },
  }
}
```

Based on my previous question here, [how to search for values when the selector is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348190/how-to-search-for-values-when-the-selector-is-an-array), 
I currently have an index added for the `collected.tags` field, but the search is still taking a long time. Here is the search query I have.

```
{
  "selector": {
    "collected.tags": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$regex": "abc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are about 300k records matching the above condition, there search seems to take a long time. So, I want to create a indexed view to retrieve and lookup faster instead of a find/search. I am new to couchdb and am not sure how to setup the map function to create the indexed view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the map function out myself. Now all the documents are indexed and retrievals are faster

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.collected.tags.indexOf('abc') > -1){
    emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```